# Understanding a proof of: In a finite group, the number of elements of prime order $p$ is divisible by $p − 1.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, cyclic-groups

I am currently attempting to understand the proof of

> Proposition 2.13. In a finite group, the number of elements of prime order $p$ is divisible by $p − 1.$

From Carrell's "Groups matrices and vector spaces".

The proof is as follows:

> By Lagrange, two distinct subgroups of prime order $p$ meet exactly at $1$, for their intersection is a subgroup of both. But in a group of order $p$, every element except the identity has order exactly $p$, since $p$ is prime. Thus the number of elements of order $p$ is $m(p − 1)$ where $m$ is the number of subgroups of order $p.$

I am having difficulty understanding why every element in the subgroups has order $p.$

I am aware that groups with prime order are cyclic. So does this imply that every element of a prime order cyclic group, except the identity, have order $p$? And if so why?

Comment: If $a$ is an element of a subgroup $H \leq G$, then the subgroup generated by $a$ is a subgroup of $H$.  That is, by Lagrange, the order of $a$ divides $|H|$.  If $|H|$ is prime, what does that tell you about the order of $a$?

Comment: In a finite group, the number of elements of order $d$ is always a multiple of $\varphi (d)$, where $\varphi $ is Euler's totient function.

Comment: "So does this imply that every element of a prime order cyclic group, except the identity, have order p? and if so why?"  Absolutely!  .... It's just LeGrange theorem....  In any finite group the order of any element $a$ will divide the order of the group. But if the group order is prime, $p$, there is nothing *but* $p$ and $1$ that divide $p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $o(G) = p$. if $a\in G - \{1\} $ then the group generated by $a$ is a subgroup of $G$, therefore its order divides $p$ and therefore it is $p$ (it cannot be 1 because then $a = 1$). Because the order of an element is the order of the group it generates, we have that every element except for the identity is of order $p$.